# How to transfer a notebook with imported data to another computer?

Tags: import, notebooks

I've been working on a notebook at home with imported data from some Excel files and plan on working on it on another computer. I have the .nb file and the .xls files, and my imported data is a suppressed output.

Sorry is this is an obvious question, I can't get the key words right in my searches for an answer.

What is the best way to transfer my notebook, all the stored variables and .xls files as one package to another computer?

Am I going to have to transfer all the files to the new computer, go into my notebook and fix the file directory for each individual time that I imported data (as the file directory will not be the same on the new computer)? Then will I have to re-evaluate every single command?

I've never actually had to transfer my notebook from one computer to another, I am always used to working on the same machine so I'm unsure as to the mechanics of moving large notebooks with imported data and lots of set variables to a new machine.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use

```
DumpSave["state.mx", "Global`"]
```

to put all the defined variables/symbols in a given instance into a file. Then you can afterwards reload that with `Get["state.mx"]`. This is probably the most 'portable state' form you can get for moving a notebook's loaded data to another computer, without moving the source data.

Comment: The .wdx format (see https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/WDX.html) can also be used. It is more platform independent